# Take until N identical numbers with RXJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have code that emits values at a certain rate :

```
let source = zip (
             interval(150) ,
              from ([0,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]) 
            )  .subscribe(a=>console.log(a))
```

I want to find the value - after `N` values have been settled ( which means - `N` repeated identical values  ) .

For example , if `N=5` , Then I need to find the first time that it yields  5 -identical values . ( and emit that value.)

**Question:**

How can I detect N identical values and emit  that value (*& complete the stream*)?

So the expected value here is `3` , since it's the first series of 5 identical values :

[image]

[*Online demo*](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dtlnax?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `bufferCount(N, 1)` where `1` tells `bufferCount` to emit its buffer after every emission which means it'll emit arrays of `N` items. Then just check that all of them are the same and complete.

```
const N = 5

from ([0,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]) 
  .pipe(
    bufferCount(N, 1),
    filter(buffer => buffer.length === N && buffer.every(i => i === buffer[0])),
    take(1),
    map(buffer => buffer[0]),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-xzb5so?file=index.ts

Comment: I think I don't understand what you want

Comment: it's possible that the source can yield `[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]`. All those 3 at the start are because of initilaztion process and I don't want them to count.  I want them to count only if there was any change.

Comment: look at all the red arrows : those are "change point" where value changes.  I need to start detecting only after a change point. https://i.imgur.com/9cx21xo.jpg . 
So - Is it possible to yield the yellow `3`'s which is after a change point ?
the initial `3`'s are not good since there is no change point before them. I want to deal only with `3`'s which has any change point before them
(I know that's not included in the question , but facing an initialization problem which does yield many same values at the start. And I don't need those. I need only those after any change point.

Comment: I guess you could use `take(2), takeLast(1)` that will ignore the first sequence

Comment: Thanks. BTW - I think I got it with this solution : so first identical stream data is not counted. Only after any change - I start counting : https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ha2u3x?file=index.ts

Answer (score 1):

it's a little ugly but this would work

```
from([0,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]).pipe(
   scan((acc, cur) => {
     if (cur !== acc.lastValue) {
       acc.count = 0;
       acc.lastValue = cur;
     } else {
       acc.count++;
       acc.lastValue = cur;
       if (acc.count >= acc.nValues) {
         acc.found = true;
       }
     }
     return acc;
   },
   {
      count: 0,
      lastValue: undefined,
      nValues: 5,
      found: false
   }),
   filter(result => result.found),
   map(result => result.lastValue),
   take(1)
).subscribe(console.log)
```